# How to solve recursive variable

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to understand how `boost::recursive_wrapper` works and I wrote the following test code.
I think using a pointer is enough to solve the recursive issue.
However, the following code compiles but has runtime error when trying to create `'a'`. Any idea why it fails and how come `boost::recursive_wrapper` works.

```
template<class T>
class w
{
public:
    w();
private:
    T *p;
};

template <class T>
w<T>::w():p(new T)
{

}

struct list
{
    int val;
    //boost::recursive_wrapper<list> Next;
    w<list> Next;

};    

void main()
{
    list a;
}
```

Comment: The code would fail in the same way with `boost::recursive_wrapper`. The point of `recursive_wrapper` is to use it in something like `boost::variant`, which won't construct it automatically.

Answer (score 2):

The `p(new T)` part in the constructor will cause infinite run time recursion.

The line

```
list a;
```

calls

```
list::list()
```

which calls

```
w<list>::w() : p (new list)
```

which calls

```
list::list()
```

and it recurses until stack overflow occurs.

Use `p(nullptr)` instead.

```
template <class T>
w<T>::w() : p(nullptr)
{
}
```